# Show an sequence that can not use l’Hôpital’s Rule to find limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits-without-lhopital

This from my textbook
[image]

I understand that the domain of a function need to be real numbers to apply l’Hôpital’s Rule.
But the textbook also provides a theorem below.
[image]

It looks like to me that we can apply l’Hôpital’s Rule every time by coming up with a function first, then apply it to the sequence.
Or we can only apply l’Hôpital’s Rule to see if the limit exists, if it exists, fine, the limit of sequence is the same limit. But if a function's limit doesn't exist, there no point to use l’Hôpital’s Rule?

Comment: Remark 1.1 makes no sense to me.It is vague and it is not clear what they are trying to state.As you observed, if the limit exists (l’Hôpital’s Rule), fine, then the limit of sequence is the same limit.In particular, this approach works for Example 1.3 shown in your question.It is true that $\sin 2\pi n$ approaches $0$ as $n\to\infty$ even if $\sin 2\pi x$ does not approach any limit as $x\to\infty$, but if they wanted to be understood, they should have provided a precise statement (which they perhaps did, as they refer to Theorem 1.2 at the end of Remark 1.1), and not get carried away talking